# Test google adsense

Tags: html, adsense

Maybe a stupid question but I am developing a script that I am selling and I would like add an ad section to the script but I can't test it because I don't have a website with very much traffic etc. so I would be denied by google. Is there a way to test google adsense like to get a google_ad_client test code or someting ?

Thanks

Comment: I know from experience google adsense denies websites over a lack of traffic. Problem is of course when you try and test for clicks, because artificial clicks are not allowed and will result in a ban for life (which means that a small community you manage can block your adsense forever, which I also know from experience...)